# Toolstrip labels do not update until I switch tabs

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.5

I know this will sound vague but I'll do my best explaining...I have a web scraper I made in C# which contains a few tabs on the interface. At the bottom is a toolstrip container with a few status labels. The main tab has a ListView which is constantly updated by other threads.

The labels are updated by a timer that runs every second.

After leaving the program running for a while, the labels no longer update while focus is on the main tab (the one with a ListView). Instead, I have to click on any other tab and then it will automatically update itself and continue to update every second.

As soon as I switch back to the main tab, updating stops. Mind you, this only happens after the program runs for a couple hours.

So, sorry for the vague question, but is there any way someone can point me in the right direction here?

Here is code for the timer:

```
private void timerRuntime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblRuntime.Text = string.Format("Runtime [{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss}]", stopWatch.Elapsed);
}
```

Thanks SO!

Comment: dear could you pleae share relavent code? and which timer you are using  is it `system.Windows.Forms.Timer?`

Comment: Sorry, added code for the timer and yes, it is a System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class does not have an `Elapsed` property. But `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` class does. So are you starting a `StopWatch` and having the `Timer` fire off the `Tick` event which reads the `StopWatch.Elapsed` property?

Comment: i think you need to use `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `SYstem.Windows.Fomrs.Timer` check my answer below

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: I'm curious as to why you say that.

Comment: I am using a stopwatch, which is defined elsewhere, to track the time elapsed. The timer just updates the label.

Comment: @blizz: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: hey yes I ended up figuring out that the other controls I was updating on the form were being updated too frequently. This was dragging the whole interface down. So I switched all of the UI updates  to run on a 1 second timer, rather than updating every single time my app receives a webresponse.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Control.Refresh Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to force the `ToolStrip` control to redraw itself:

```
private void timerRuntime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      lblRuntime.Text = string.Format("Runtime [{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss}]", stopWatch.Elapsed);
      toolStrip1.Refresh();
}
```

Description of `Refresh()` method from MSDN:

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately
>   redraw itself and any child controls.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense...I will try this one first and see if it helps. I'll post back.

Comment: I used ResumeLayout on every single control. I used Invalidate() on every single control. Refresh finally works. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `System.Timers.Timer`

Try This:

```
    System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 60000;//one minute
    timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      lblRuntime.Text = string.Format(
           "Runtime [{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss}]", stopWatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

Comment: While it is true that `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will not raise events that occur while the UI thread is unable to process them. The `System.Timers.Timer` will just queue the events to be processed when the UI thread is available. I don't see how that it relevant to the OPs issue - How will queuing the events fix their issue of the `ToolStripLabel` displaying the time elapsed?

Answer (score 0):

test that: (some time form dont be reloded)

```
Invoke(new Action(() => lblRuntime.Text = string.Format("Runtime [{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss}]", stopWatch.Elapsed)));
```